# Rails 3.2 - Validate in Model Based on Other Model Criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have an AWARD model - there are two forms to create an AWARD.  One is for nominating EMPLOYEES, the other is for Non-Employees.  The EMPLOYEE form pulls a list of active employees to populate the Nominee selection box.  The Non-Employee form has only text fields to populate the Nominee field (because I have no source to populate a selection list).

To dummy-proof the app, I want to run a validation that disallows Employees from using the Non-Employee form (because they will inevitably try to do so!).  There is a hidden field on each form to set whether the form is Employee or Non:  `<%= f.hidden_field :employee, :value => true/false %>`

So, on the Non-Employee form, if the user types in a nominee_username that exists in the Employee table, it should throw an error and direct them to the Employee form.

Here's what I've attempted:

```
class Award < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :nominator, :class_name => 'Employee', :foreign_key => 'nominator_id'
  belongs_to :nominee, :class_name => 'Employee', :foreign_key => 'nominee_id'

  validate :employee_using_non_employee_form,
                                :on => :create, :unless => :employee_nomination?


  def employee_nomination?
   self.employee == true
  end

  def employee_using_non_employee_form
    if nominee_username == employee.username  ##  --  this is where I'm getting errors.  I get "undefined local variable or method employee for #<Award:.."
                                              ## I've also tried Employee.username, but get "undefined method username for #<Class..."
                                              ## Same error when I try nominee.username
      errors.add(:nominator, "Please use Employee form.")
    end
  end

end
```

There is an association between the Award and Employee models, but I don't know how to call the Employee.username within the Award model to validate the Non-Employee form.

```
  class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :awards, :foreign_key => 'nominator_id'
      has_many :awards, :foreign_key => 'nominee_id'
  end
```

Comment: What about this? `if Employee.where(:username => nominee_username).present?`

Comment: Hm, and I can put that in the validation method in the award model?  Will try it... sheesh, so EASY.  Thank you!!  Wanna answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Nice, glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your validation method.

```
def employee_using_non_employee_form
  if Employee.where(:username => nominee_username).present?
    errors.add(:nominator, "Please use Employee form.")
  end
end
```